# SharePoint 2010 SandBox Consuming web service (lists.asmx)

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sandbox

Is this possible to consume a webservice from sandbox in SharePoint 2010. 
I want to use http://mysite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx to create a new list item. 
Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

no you unfortunately can't.  Sandbox Solutions are limited to the current site collection. In addition to that access to network resources is also prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a [full-trust proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622616.aspx)?